# Unit Testing Components utilizing "ChartJS" with Jest and Enyzme in TypeScript for React Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to unit test (`RiskChartComponent.spec.ts`) a React component in my application named `RiskChartComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import RiskChartComponent from '../RiskChartComponent/RiskChartComponent'

describe('RiskChartComponent', () => {

    it('should render successfully', () => {
        const props = { xAxisArray: [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4], yAxisArray: [-491.11, -392.11, -305.38, -140.15, -6.74, 6.18, 44.77, -12.04, -190.24], label: 'Delta', context: '2d'};

        const wrapped = shallow(<RiskChartComponent{...props} />, { lifecycleExperimental: true });

        expect(wrapped).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

But when I run `npm test --watch` this unit test always fails with the following error:
[image]

My component I'm trying to unit test is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import Chart from "chart.js";

interface RiskChartViewModel {
    xAxisArray: any[];
    yAxisArray: any[];
    label:string;
}

export default class RiskChartComponent extends React.Component<RiskChartViewModel, {}> {    
    chartRef:any = React.createRef();
    datacollection: any;

    fillData() {
        this.datacollection = {
            labels: this.props.xAxisArray,
            datasets: [{
                label: this.props.label,
                data: this.props.yAxisArray,
                backgroundColor: ['rgba(0, 35, 93, 0.2)'],
                borderColor: ['rgba(0, 35, 93, 1)']
            }]
        };
    }
    
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.buildGraph();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.buildGraph();
    }

    buildGraph()
    {
        const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");
        this.fillData();

        new Chart(myChartRef, {
            type: "line",
            data: this.datacollection,
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display:false
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: {
                        display:true,
                        labelString: 'Delta'
                    },
                    xAxes: [{
                        display:true,
                        labelString:'Price',
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                return '$' + value;
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row" >
                <div className="col-sm-8">
                    <div className="card">
                        <canvas id="myChart" ref={this.chartRef} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In my initial research it seems that Jest uses `jsdom` for mocking the necessary parts of the DOM to be able to run the tests in Node, thus avoiding style calculation and rendering that a browser would normally do. Do I then need to mock `Chart.js` in this unit test to get it to work? How would I go about doing that in this instance?

Comment: *Do I then need to mock Chart.js in this unit test to get it to work?* - yes. Most third-party libs need to be mocked for unit tests. Especially the ones that rely on real DOM that Jest environment cannot provide.

Comment: @EstusFlask, according to some of these comments... I wouldn't need to Mock out if I'm using `shallow`? 
https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2/issues/155
How would I mock out `Chart.Js` in this instance?

Comment: Totally depends on the case. You cited an issue from React lib where its components indeed won't be rendered with shallow, it's not applicable to yours because you use Chart directly. Basically you need to mock Chart API in a minimal way that will allow tests pass. I.e. make `Chart` a spy and mock `chartRef.current` to have `getContext` spy method. You could alternatively try jest-canvas-mock but no guarantees that the lib won't fail elsewhere.

Comment: @EstusFlask I tried adding the following to my `setupJest.js` file:
`jest.mock('chart.js', () => ({
    Chart: () => null
  }));`
But it seems that it's still failing at `this.chartRef.current.getContent("2d");` line with the following error still:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`

Comment: @EstusFlask I figured it out... i needed to update `lifecycleExperimental: true` to `disableLifecycleMethods: true` in addition to the mocking code I added.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After some research.... I added the following code to my `setupJest.ts` file:

```
jest.mock('chart.js', () => ({
    Chart: () => null
  }));
```

Then in my `RiskChartComponent.spec.ts` file I removed `context` parameter of `2d` being passed in and updated the `lifecycleExperimental: true` to `disableLifecycleMethods: true`. And the test passed for me:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import RiskChartComponent from '../RiskChartComponent/RiskChartComponent';

describe('RiskChartComponent', () => {

    it('should render successfully', () => {

        const currentContext = React.createRef().current;
        const props = { xAxisArray: [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4], yAxisArray: [-491.11, -392.11, -305.38, -140.15, -6.74, 6.18, 44.77, -12.04, -190.24], label: 'Delta'};

        const wrapped = shallow(<RiskChartComponent{...props} />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });

        expect(wrapped).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: That throws an error of `Uncaught [TypeError: _chart.default is not a constructor]`